# Why is that when I attempt to verify an archive using tar I am displayed the error this does not look like a tar archive?

Tags: linux, tar

[image]

I am new to the world of linux and when attempting to verify a tar archive I am displayed the following error. When running the command tar cvfW archivename.tar filename directoryname does not yield any errors.

Comment: Okay, after you posting this phrase five times (at least) we now are all aware that you're "new to the world of linux". :)

Comment: @ErikA - Just like to point out the questions are from a linux newbie

Comment: Understood - that doesn't really matter. Post your question - it'll get answered by and large regardless of the skill level of the OP.

Comment: I should add that you ought to make sure that you're adhering to the FAQ with regards to what is on-topic and what is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the options in the wrong order.  f is for file, so it has to be last the way you are doing it.

```
tar cvWf tarball.tar *.txt
```

Create, Verbose, Verify, File

```
[powellnj@insomnia ~]$ touch {1,2,3}.txt
[powellnj@insomnia ~]$ tar cvWf tarball.tar *.txt
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
Verify 1.txt
Verify 2.txt
Verify 3.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that it doesn't work either if I am using the -t argument/switch i.e. tar tvWf archivename.tar. Also I am following the guide at http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/unix-tar-command-examples/

Comment: The W only works during creation.  'tar tvf tarball.tar' will do what you want. man tar: -W, --verify attempt to verify the archive after writing it

Comment: So the meaning of `after writing it` is only when using -c? Am surprised though that the article suggest I can use it when -t.

Comment: It doesn't say what implementation of tar they are using. tar differs on different platforms.  If you want to learn to use tar on Linux, you need to find a tutorial that is GNU specific.

Comment: I did not know that. How do I check if the version of tar I am using is GNU specific.